# Gnome Shell: Move windows to front on launch (No more "... is ready to use" notifications)

Tags: gnome, notification, focus

I've been using Gnome Shell with Ubuntu for few days now and have experienced really annoying behaviour with new windows.

Sometimes when I use another window and press e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> to open new terminal window, the new window is not brought to the front. Instead I get a "New terminal window is ready to use" notification.

A similar problem occurs with the with Pidgin being integrated with Gnome Shell (via extension). When I get a new message, a notification pops up, but the window does not show. I need to either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it or click the notification to see the new message.

Is there any way to have new windows being always brought to front, and remove those annoying "Window is ready" notifications?

**EDIT:** `gconftool-2 --search-key focus_new_windows` (as requested by severin):

```
 /schemas/apps/metacity/general/focus_new_windows = Schema (type: `string' list_type: '*invalid*' car_type: '*invalid*' cdr_type: '*invalid*' locale: `C')
 /apps/metacity/general/focus_new_windows = smart
```

Comment: There is a good reason why Gnome shows that "Window is ready" notification when a new window is opened without getting focus automatically. It is a important accessibility feature. For the blind and other visually impaired users like me it is important to get notified if a window without focus is opened because otherwise it would be impossible to know if the window really was not opened or not. If a new window does not get focus automatically then user must be notified so that users knows that the window opened. Screen reader like Orca speaks those notifications.

Comment: In Debian v3.16, Gnome 3 I found this **focus_new_windows** setting in **org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences**

Comment: if a new window gets focus automatically (especially with a shell) while I am typing stuff, I get pretty angry… also think about potential security consequences

Comment: "There is a good reason" ? no. There is no good reason to make a system less usable and less secure.
This is a result of a mistake that should be corrected. At least the ability to disable this bug should be put at the hands of the user.

Comment: There is a similar question on AskUbuntu with more answers: https://askubuntu.com/q/80969/2355

Answer (score 18):

## GNOME extension: "Steal My Focus"

There is an extension for Gnome 3 called "steal my focus" by  sstent.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/234/steal-my-focus/

It solves the exact problem you're having.

Comment: doesn't work for me. I noticed that I'm having this problem only on my external monitor. On the laptop display the window comes in front.

Comment: A great extension!

Comment: This worked for me, Gnome 3.14.

Comment: This worked for me GNOME Ubuntu 15.04 - Gnome 3.14

Comment: Doesn't work on GNOME 3.22.2 (Fedora 25)

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/ is the more up to date option.

Comment: @lkraav I converted your comment to an answer, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: On arch-linux, you can install it as a package via https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gnome-shell-extension-stealmyfocus-git and then need to restart for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This doesn't work on newer versions of Ubuntu, which have newer versions of GNOME.

Answer (score 14):

On Ubuntu 20.04 without installing anything you can use these 2 commands in a Terminal as a workaround:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences auto-raise 'true'`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'strict'`

No need of extensions or additional Applications.

Comment: Should be `focus-new-windows 'smart'` so that windows opened via Terminal can gain focus immediately. With `'strict'`, Terminal opens windows in the background with a notification.

Comment: even only auto-raise did the trick (to show immediately the "open file" dialog from my IDE)

Comment: Did not work for me on RHEL 8 (GNOME 3.32.2). I tried `strict` and `smart`.

Comment: `focus-new-windows` should not be set to `strict`, but `smart` (the default value) to get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

You can try setting focus_new_windows from smart to strict.
You can either use gconf-editor and go to /apps/metacity/general and change the value of focus_new_windows from smart to strict, like here:[image]

Or you can use the command line:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/focus_new_windows --type string strict
```

If that still doesn't help, you can also change auto_raise_delay from 1000 to 0 in aforementioned gconf-editor (see screenshot).

See also [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=899590).

Comment: But the long description given for focus_new_windows key says "This option provides additional control over how newly created windows get focus. It has two possible values; "smart" applies the user's normal focus mode, and "strict" results in windows started from a terminal not being given focus."

But we want the opposite . Isnt it ? We want to give focus for newly launched applications. How to do that?

Comment: Running that command-line had no effect for me

Comment: Also had no effect for me (I have it set both to strict and the auto_raise_delay to 0).

Comment: `gconf-editor` does not exist on Ubuntu 23.10, and neither does `gconftool-2`

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to **System** > **Preferences** > **CompizConfig Settings Manager** > **General Options** (under *General*) > **Focus & Raise Behaviour**,
2. Clear **Focus Prevention Windows** field.

References: [Compiz General Options](http://wiki.compiz.org/GeneralOptions), [Compiz Window Matching](http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching).

Answer (score 3):

## GNOME extension: "NoAnnoyance"

Try installing and activating this GNOME extension called NoAnnoyance by sindex:

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/

The [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sindex/no-annoyance) seems more up-to-date than some of the answers listed here.

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me. I thought you only needed 3rd party apps to fix idiotic UX decisions on Mac? :-D

Comment: As of writing, this extension does not support GNOME versions newer than GNOME 43, so it won't work on Ubuntu 23.10.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is a setting to do this. I have been using gnome shell for a while now. You can install the "advanced settings extension" for gnome 3 which provides you with a few more settings. However, you cannot get the function you are looking for. I will search the net and come back to you.

Comment: Nope, as far as I'm concerned there is no way to do autofocussing a new window nor is there a way to remove the notifications.

Comment: there is an extension for gnome which does that exact thing you're saying isn't possible. Have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This can now be done within Tweak Tool which is included with Gnome Shell.  You no longer need to use extensions or `dconf-editor`.

Under the "Windows" section, slide the switch over for "Automatically Raise Windows".

This setting will make windows popup in focus, ***and*** will also get rid of the "application is ready" notification.

[image]

EDIT: This option is missing in Ubuntu 17.10 and will hopefully be back in 18.04.  As a temporary fix, you can try installing the following gnome extensions;

- Noannoyance
- Focus my window
- Steal my focus

The above extension are available here : https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: This setting is absent on gnome-tweak-tool in Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @ChrisBillington Correct.  The reasoning for the removal isn't clear.  However, you can get these back by installing the Gnome extensions "NoAnnoyance" and "Focus my window".  Hopefully they bring it back in 18.04.  I usually only stick with LTS releases... Also as mentioned below, the extension "Steal my focus" may work for you.

Comment: The setting is there in 19.10 but does not work

Comment: The setting is absent in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

The long term solution is for this bug to be fixed by the developers.

Here is a bug report that seems to be related:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1825710

Maybe casting more votes will eventually help the solution..

Answer (score 1):

1. use `gconf-editor`
2. go to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/focus-new-windows`
3. set property: "strict"
4. apply changes

[image]

Comment: To install `gconf-editor`, run `sudo apt install gconf-editor`

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, the path `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/focus-new-windows` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this type of stuff with `devilspie`, which has a nice GUI frontend `gdevilspie`, which is in the repos.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom shortcut under your keyboard settings
and use command:
xterm -e **< terminalname >**
or:
uxterm -e **< terminalname >**

Also if you get problems with "failed to execute session" you can always go a step further.


**< terminalname >** -e xterm -e **< terminalname >**

In my case: 
xfce4-terminal -e xterm -e xfce4-terminal

This i kinda funny because in this way you use a native terminal to start the newer one.
And since the older don't have the preference to start in background
it will start the newer on top.

Clean and no need to install extensions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've had this issue for many months. After going through all answers, I found nothing satisfactory, but some good pointers. And here's the full answer that solved my problem for Ubuntu 18.04: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux.

### Step 1

Install Firefox Addon that makes it easy to install GNOME Shell extensions: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/.

### Step 2

Install the host connector that supports the addon:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

### Step 3

Install this GNOME Shell extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/. You can install it from the web page, thanks to the Firefox extension.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04, the following has worked for me.

1. Install the NoAnnoyance GNOME Shell Extension by entering in a terminal window

   `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-no-annoyance`
2. Then launch GNOME Tweaks by entering in the terminal

   `gnome-tweaks`
3. In Tweaks, make sure to [enable Noannoyance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy2j1.png) under Extensions

Comment: That package does not exist in Ubuntu 23.10's repositories.

Answer (score 0):

## GNOME extension: "NoAnnoyance v2"

"NoAnnoyance v2" by bjoerndaase is a fork of "NoAnnoyance", it's a separate GNOME extension, and is not merely the second version of "NoAnnoyance", despite the name. It removes the 'Window is ready' notification and puts the window into focus.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/

Comment: Sadly, this extension does not currently support GNOME versions greater than 43. So it won't work on Ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 0):

## GNOME extension: Grand Theft Focus

There's another GNOME extension that address this problem. This one works on GNOME 45, which ships with Ubuntu 23.10.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5410/grand-theft-focus/

Answer (score 0):

## GNOME extension: "Window Is Ready - Notification Remover"

This extension by nunofarruca also removes the notification "Window is ready", and it works on GNOME 45, the version of GNOME that ships with Ubuntu 23.10.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1007/window-is-ready-notification-remover/