# Focused window is not in front

Tags: gnome, focus

Since I upgraded<sup>1</sup> from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10, I stumbled upon a really frustrating bug of gnome: if I click on a window, it correctly gets the focus but *stays in the background* (see screenshot below).

Please note that this issue is not related to any particular window or application. It's the whole window manager that screws up!

[image: Screen capture of the strange behaviour]

*Here, I clicked on the firefox' window, it get the focus --- I can enter keyboard shortcuts for instance --- but the gnome-terminal window sits there ...*

If I <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, the newly focused window is correctly put in the front.

---

<sup>1)</sup> I've got the exact same issue with a newly installed Ubuntu 15.10 from scratch. Maybe it is related to my configuration (I kept my `$HOME` folder).

---

#### Envirnment

- Linux 4.2 on x86_64
- Ubuntu 15.10
- gnome-session 3.16.0-1ubuntu2
- (ask for more)

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Check this thread: http://askubuntu.com/q/80969/

Comment: @whtyger Unfortunately, this is not the same issue, though it is related to focus. I tried the suggested solutions anyway (who knows?) but it didn't help.

Comment: Gnome-terminal does have a function "always on top". Normally you can check and un-check it with a right mouse click in the upper part of the terminal. (right from the minimize, maximize, close box). Did you check that already?

Comment: I did. This is not related to the "always on top" feature I think. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of *Phrostatus*, I ended up opening `gconf-editor` and something bizarre happened when I played with its keys. When I opened `gnome-tweak-tool`, it did not display the same configuration as `gconf-editor` would. It smelled fishy.

The solution, quite radical, was to reset my entire `gnome-session` configuration.

1. Back it up!

   ```
   mkdir ./.gnome-config.bak/ && mv ./.gnome* ./.gnome-config.bak/ && mv .gconf* ./.gnome-config.bak/ && mv ./.metacity ./.gnome-config.bak/ && mv ./.cache ./.gnome-config.bak/ && mv ./.dbus ./.gnome-config.bak/ && mv ./.dmrc ./.gnome-config.bak/ && mv ./.mission-control ./.gnome-config.bak/ && mv ./.thumbnails ./.gnome-config.bak/   && mv ~/.config/dconf/* ./.gnome-config.bak/
   ```
2. Kill it with fire!

   ```
   rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
   ```
3. Close and reopen you session...
4. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2043536&p=12181476#post12181476) out?
It's for an older version of Ubuntu (10.04), but the problem seems similar to yours, so it might be worth checking out.

> > > August 19th, 2012 by A Traveller
>
> Re: Windows staying on top Thanks Frogs Hair. Your suggestion has
>   fixed the problem! Here is what I did:-
>
> Press 'Alt + F2'     Typed 'gconf-editor' and clicked 'Run'
>   Expanded 'Apps', then 'Metacity' and the clicked on 'General'
>   Double-clicked 'raise_on_click' and changed the 'Value' to 'True' by
>   clicking on the button which said 'False'       Clicked 'OK' and then
>   closed the Gconf Editor window     Voila!
>
> I have read warnings advising against changing the Value to False, but
>   can't remember ever changing it to False. I have played with the
>   location of the maximize, minimize and close buttons but I don't know
>   how the raise-on-click got changed. I did install Ubuntu Tweak
>   recently but don't know if anything I may have changed in that caused
>   the problem.

Comment: It did not solve my problem, but it lead me to the solution. So thank you.