# How to skip the "Is ready" notification and directly open apps in Ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: desktop-apps

On Ubunto Focal Fossa 20.4, for most of the apps, for example by searching for VeraCrypt and pressing Enter, Ubuntu displays a notification at the top of my screen which says something like "VeraCrypt is ready". I have to click on this notification so that the app I wanted to open comes to the foreground. Is there a way to change this default behavior?

Comment: The notification replaces an older behavior. That older behavior, commonly  called "window-stealing,' was a common source of user confusion and complaints.

Comment: @user535733 Why didn't Ubuntu just change that behavior by only allowing applications that were manually opened by the user to be focused?

Comment: Ubuntu did not change the behavior. Gnome did. Feel free to ask the Gnome developers (whom we are not).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gnome Shell: Move windows to front on launch (No more "... is ready to use" notifications)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80969/gnome-shell-move-windows-to-front-on-launch-no-more-is-ready-to-use-noti)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are some Gnome extensions that do exactly that:

- [Window Is Ready - Notification Remover](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1007/window-is-ready-notification-remover/)
- [Focus my window](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1005/focus-my-window/)

Answer (score 17):

Windows is Ready - Notification Remover <-- only removes notification, does not focus the open window

Focus my window <-- incompatible

Here, this works best on Ubuntu 22.04

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5410/grand-theft-focus/

Comment: Grand Theft Focus worked for me. I didn't test the others because of this answer. I used the NoAnnoyance extension initially but it didn't seem to work on 22.04.

Comment: This is more maintained than "Focus my window" ("Focus my window" does not work is 43).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer @pLumo

Comment: 1. `sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell` . 2. open https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5410/grand-theft-focus/  , and install the chrome extension if not yet. 3. click `install` on the site, then it should work. (it worked on my ubuntu 22.04.3)