# How to bring a winow to front when you open a file in a text editor Gnome Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome

Every time I open a file in a text editor from double panel file manager - I get a pop-up: Geany is ready OR Geany's icon it just rotates at the task bar (annoying animation). I want it to come to the front even though I open the same application but a new tab. Is it possible?

I tried every option is this question: [Gnome Shell: Move windows to front on launch (No more "... is ready to use" notifications)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80969/gnome-shell-move-windows-to-front-on-launch-no-more-is-ready-to-use-noti)

It doesn't work. I don't remember how I accomplish that but it was definitely there in ubuntu 20.04. Maybe I should type something particular into CompizConfig?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install the Gnome Shell extension [NoAnnoyance v2 by bjoerndaase](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/).

Sometimes, extensions include this as one of their options, e.g. [Just Perfection by JustPerfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) or [Unite by hardpixel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/).